# htop graphics cut off in AWS Ubuntu

Tags: graphics, aws, htop

`htop` is not working properly on an AWS Ubuntu instance. <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> do nothing.

Does anybody come across this issue?
This screenshot shows that `htop` only shows part of the graphics.

[image: This screenshot shows that htop only shows part of the graphics]

Comment: F2, go to Meters, Left column, choose CPUs and hit the Delete key.

Comment: Unfortunately, F2 does nothing and alt-F2 does nothing.